# How to resolve dependency conflict for spring boot 3 and hibernate search

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-search-6

I habe the following dependencies within my data module:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-mapper-orm-jakarta</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-backend-lucene</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>


+ org.hibernate.search:hibernate-search-mapper-orm-jakarta:6.1.7.Final
└── org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.1.2.Final
  + org.hibernate:hibernate-core-jakarta:5.6.11.Final
  └── org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.1.2.Final
  + org.hibernate.search:hibernate-search-mapper-pojo-base:6.1.7.Final
  └── org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.1.2.Final

+ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.0.5
└── + org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.1.7.Final
    └── org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:6.0.6.Final
```

The conflict is between **hibernate-commons-annotations:5.1.2.Final** from hibernate-search-mapper-orm-jakarta and **hibernate-commons-annotations:6.0.6.Final** from spring-boota-starter-data-jpa dependency.

I want to use hibernate search(with jakarta persistence) and spring boot 3.0.5. How can I achieve this. Can I somehow tell spring to use onother version of hibernate core?

Thanks and Best Regards
Matt

Comment: There is another problem that you may face right after. `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` does not work with `hibernate-core-jakarta`

Comment: Yes at the moment I am stuck because of this. The exclusion does not solve the problem entirely.

Comment: @Matt have you managed to use hibernate-search with SpringBoot 3? Can you share your configs?

Comment: @Alex There is a hint within the documentation https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.1/ under the Jakarta EE and Hibernate ORM 6 but it says the artifacts are still experimental (beta). See also https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#other-integrations-orm6

Answer (score 1):

You have two alternatives, lifting the hibernate-commons-annotations to 6.0.6.Final or dropping the hibernate-commons-annotations to 5.1.2.Final.

To lift the org.hibernate.search:hibernate-commons-annotations to 6.0.6.Final, simply exclude it from org.hibernate.search:hibernate-search-mapper-orm-jakarta:6.1.7.Final. Then hibernate-search-mapper-orm-jakarta will use the class provided via spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.0.5 via hibernate-core:6.1.7.Final

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-mapper-orm-jakarta</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

To drop the hibernate-commons-annotations to 5.1.2.Final from the 6.0.6.Final arising from the org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.0.5 dependency (which is loading org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.1.7 & hibernate-commons-annotations:6.0.6.Final) add the following pom dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

A possible problem with the second approach is that you lose the intermediate org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core. It depends on what your code does. If required you can fix by adding the following pom dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are separate artifacts for jakarta as you can read in the [documentation](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.1/#jakarta) to hibernate search 6.1. And from there you are leaded to the proper artifacts:

- org.hibernate.hibernate-core-jakarta:5.6.12.Final (or newer)
- org.hibernate.search.hibernate-search-mapper-orm-jakarta:6.1.8.Final (or newer)

Then everything should work.